# Formatting txt file with sed script

Tags: python-3.x, sed

I have a text file with a few hundred lines in it. In those lines are varying numbers of email addresses (all of the same domain). I want to change those email addresses from the format of `user1@domain.com` to `domain\user1`.

I tried using the below sed script against the source file of IDs.txt, but it errored out with the corresponding error message:

```
with open(IDs.txt, '+') as f:
    f.write(
        re.sub(r'(\w+)@domain\.com', r'domain\\\1', f.read())
    )
```

Ran script with this command:

```
sed -Ef id.sed
```

Error:

```
sed: file id.sed line 2: unknown command: `f'
```

From what I looked up sed may not even write to files, so is this even possible to work or am I wasting time? Thanks.

---EDIT---

Sample contents of the source file:

```
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy source-user [ name1@domain.com userid@domain.com userid1@domain.com userid3@domain.com ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy11552 source-user [ userid6@domain.com userid5@domain.com userid4@domain.com userid7@domain.com ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolict00988 source-user userid10@domain.com
```

Expected output:

```
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy source-user [ domain\name1 domain\userid domain\userid1 domain\userid3 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy11552 source-user [ domain\userid6 domain\userid5 domain\userid4 domain\userid7 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolict00988 source-user domain\userid10
```

Comment: Um, that's python not sed. The `sed` program doesn't know how to execute python code

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @JamesBrown, I have added the requested information to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]]+)@([^.]*)[^ ]*/\2\\\1/g' IDs.txt 
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy source-user [ domain\name1 domain\userid domain\userid1 domain\userid3 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy11552 source-user [ domain\userid6 domain\userid5 domain\userid4 domain\userid7 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolict00988 source-user domain\userid10
```

Using `python`

```
import re
f = open("IDs.txt")
output = re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]+)@([^.]*)[^ ]*', r"\2\\\1", f.read())
print(output)
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy source-user [ domain\name1 domain\userid domain\userid1 domain\userid3 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolicy11552 source-user [ domain\userid6 domain\userid5 domain\userid4 domain\userid7 ]
set device-group AllPeople TestingPolict00988 source-user domain\userid10
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, thank you! Only oddity I found is that when the email addresses begin with a capital letter, that capital letter is will prepend the newly formatted ID. For instance Luserid1@domain.com was formatted to Ldomain\userid1 (python only, SED example works fine).

Comment: Was able to correct that by changing [a-z0-9] to [A-Za-z0-9]. Thanks.